# How to detect incoming mail in iPhone programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hook into incoming call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417658/hook-into-incoming-call)
>   [Being notified when mail arrives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000823/being-notified-when-mail-arrives)

what frameworks or code should we use to detect an incoming email in ios devices. I want to detect an incoming email and send the notification message to a bluetooth LE device to notify the user

Comment: Apple consider those that type of information private. But if you can provide a use case, you should provide a feedback to Apple.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.  Apple do not provide any API to read emails or receive notifications when they arrive.